# Convert scala nested list to java.util.List

Tags: java, list

I have seen many articles on converting nested lists from scala to java. But it doesn't work for me, because i get ClassCastException.
I would like to iterate over a list using the java language, but I only have the type of the Object on the input to the method, and then I need to convert it from scala to java for iteration.

My code:

```
private boolean checkToPrimitiveType(Object o, Field field) {
    if (o instanceof Number || o instanceof Boolean || o instanceof Duration) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o.getClass().getCanonicalName().startsWith("scala.collection")) {
        // convert from scala list to java list for iterating in the future. Error ClassCastException
        list((List<?>) new AsJavaCollection<Object>((scala.collection.Iterable<Object>) o));
    }
    return false;
}

private void list(List<?> list) {
    // iterate by list using java.util.List
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided my problem, but JavaConverters is deprecated and if you have another solution, please help to me

```
java.util.List<String> convert(scala.collection.Seq<String> seq) {
    return scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(seq);
}
```